# matching date column within date range columns and summing values column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match, apply

I need to sum the daily values in pandas column (sample_sales) if they fall within date range, represented by 2 columns (payment_start and payment_end), matched in the same row with the daily date column (date). I want to output next month payment to monthly_payment column, monthly_payment is the desired output. I entered just the beginning monthly values to save space, but the range here is daily.

```
    date        payment_start    payment_end    sample_sales   monthly_payment     next_month_duration 
    2017-11-05  2017-10-01       2017-11-04     1               0                  28
    2017-11-06  2017-10-01       2017-11-04     2               0                  28
    ...         ...              ...            ...             ...
    2017-12-03  2017-11-05       2017-12-02     2               3                  28
    2017-12-04  2017-11-05       2017-12-02     2               3                  28
    ...         ...              ...            ...             ...
    2017-12-31  2017-12-03       2017-12-30     3               4                  35
    2018-01-01  2017-12-03       2017-12-30     3               4                  35
    ...         ...              ...            ...             ...
    2017-02-04  2017-12-31       2018-02-03     4               6                  28
    2017-02-05  2017-12-31       2018-02-03     4               6                  28
```

The duration of months follows the following repeating pattern 35, 28, 28 days, so it's not as easy to shift the sample_sales by a month.

I am currently using this function where I added next_month_duration:

```
    df['monthly_payment'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(df['payment_start'] + df['next_month_duration'] <= x.name) & (x.name <= df['payment_end'] + df['next_month_duration']), ['sample_sales']].sum(), axis=1)
```

The problem that I'am facing is that by pushing the sum of sample_sales by next_month_duration, leaves blanks values or double sums because of 28 and 35 days month duration.

Ultimately, I want to sum the values in monthly_payment from previous month based on the date range and to assign the summed value to each date in the following month inside the monthly_payment column.

Comment: Please read how to make a [MCVE], we would need a sample input and expected output, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to make a reproducible pandas example

Comment: @DJK bookmarked the link and noted, will rework the question. thank you for the feedback.